# JAXB un/marshalling: Is there a difference between using arrays and lists?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm fairly new to JAXB and am eager to learn more about it. 
What I've noticed is that when marshalling, the XML representation of the objects from an array and list are the identical.

What I'm interested in finding out is how JAXB treats the two data structures when un/marshalling and if it's better to standardize it to use one over the other? 
If so, what is the difference between the two (performance-wise, etc.)? 
Also, what should I consider when choosing a container for my objects?

Any information will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML representation both arrays and `List`s have the same form. When unmarshaling an XML, JAXB will choose the type you have in your Java class.

It's possible to unmarshal a collection to an array which was marshalled from a `List` and vice versa.

Both arrays and `List`s have their pros and cons. Use what is better for your purpose. In general `List` are easier to use because you have utility methods like [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), but `List`s cannot be used for primitive types. Arrays can be faster but are less flexible.

It's really up to you which you use and which is better for you.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things to consider:

1. A JAXB implementation will likely use a SAX or StAX parser to process the XML.  As it can't easily know how many items will ultimately be present in the XML it will most likely put them items in a `List` first anyways and then convert it to an array.
2. JAXB impls support multi-dimensional arrays but not multi-dimensional lists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between List or array for marshalling or unmarshalling. It can work in the both senses, when you marshal an array/List, you can unmarshal a List/array.

There is a simple example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class JAXBExample {

    @XmlElement(name = "list")
    private List<Elm> list;
    @XmlElement(name = "array")
    private Elm[] array;

    public JAXBExample() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.array = new Elm[0];
    }

    public void addList(Elm elm) {
        this.list.add(elm);
    }

    public void addArray(Elm elm) {
        Elm[] tmp = new Elm[array.length+1];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, tmp, 0, array.length);
        tmp[array.length] = elm;
        this.array = tmp;
    }

    private void clear() {
        this.array = null;
        this.list.clear();
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "element")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    static class Elm {

        @XmlElement(name = "name")
        private final String name;

        public Elm() {
            this.name = "noname";
        }

        public Elm(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... arg) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBExample.class,
            Elm.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        JAXBExample jaxb = new JAXBExample();
        jaxb.addArray(new Elm("Elm1"));
        jaxb.addArray(new Elm("Elm3"));
        jaxb.addArray(new Elm("Elm5"));
        jaxb.addArray(new Elm("Elm7"));
        jaxb.addArray(new Elm("Elm9"));
        jaxb.addList(new Elm("Elm2"));
        jaxb.addList(new Elm("Elm4"));
        jaxb.addList(new Elm("Elm6"));
        jaxb.addList(new Elm("Elm8"));
        jaxb.addList(new Elm("Elm10"));

        File f = new File("example.xml");
        marshaller.marshal(jaxb, f);

        jaxb.clear();
        jaxb = null;

        jaxb = (JAXBExample) unmarshaller.unmarshal(f);
        for (Elm elm : jaxb.array) {
            System.out.println("ArrayElm: " + elm.name);
        }
        for (Elm elm : jaxb.list) {
            System.out.println("ListElm: " + elm.name);
        }

    }
}
```

That produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ROOT>
    <list>
        <name>Elm2</name>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>Elm4</name>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>Elm6</name>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>Elm8</name>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>Elm10</name>
    </list>
    <array>
        <name>Elm1</name>
    </array>
    <array>
        <name>Elm3</name>
    </array>
    <array>
        <name>Elm5</name>
    </array>
    <array>
        <name>Elm7</name>
    </array>
    <array>
        <name>Elm9</name>
    </array>
</ROOT>
```

As you can see, the both array and list have the same storing format.